# Computing the mean value function for a nonhomogeneous poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am reading a paper in which a nonhomogeneous Poisson process is constructed with intensity function
$$ \lambda(t) =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0.42 &\text{ for } t \in [0, 121),  \\
      0.35 &\text{ for } t \in [121, 244), \\
      0.40 &\text{ for } t \in [244, 365). \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$ 
Then we are told the expectation (i.e., what I assume is the mean value function) of the process is given by
$$ \Lambda(t) =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0.38t &\text{ for } t \in [0, 121),  \\
      0.35t + 45.98 &\text{ for } t \in [121, 244), \\
      0.40t + 85.4 &\text{ for } t \in [244, 365). \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$ 
Where did these values come from? My understanding is that, for $t \in [0, 121)$, we should have that
$$ \Lambda(t) = \int_{0}^t0.42ds = 0.42t; $$
and for $t \in [121, 244)$, we should have that
$$ \Lambda(t) = \int_{121}^t 0.35ds = 0.35t - 42.35; $$
etc.

What am I missing here? (Note that——for whatever reason——I cannot find a single example online where a similar computation is done.)

Comment: Something is amiss. If indeed $\Lambda(t) = \int_0^t\lambda(s)\ \mathsf ds$ then clearly we should have $\Lambda(t)=\lambda(t)$ for $t\in[0,121)$ at the very least.